# Can't boot to Windows 7 after uninstalling and removing Linux partitions

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot, toshiba-laptop

I have a class in college for System Administration. I partitioned the disk so I could put Fedora onto my computer and dual boot it.

It was working fine until I ran out of space in the partition for Fedora. So I tried to boot from the Fedora disk and now my disk drive is dead. It tries to read but starts up and then fails a few seconds into trying to read.

So my teacher helped me a bit by installing Ubuntu ontop of the Fedora partition through a flash drive. Then I booted into Windows 7 to get rid of this random 2GB partition made by Fedora for some reason. I deleted that and the Ubuntu one and rebooted my computer.

Now I get an error saying something like "no partitions". But obviously, Windows 7 is still on there with its recovery partition too! However I can't access either by my computer's boot menu and have to boot to Ubuntu on flash drive to get into Windows 7.

In the end, I want to get rid of Ubuntu and just keep Windows 7 on my computer and have it boot directly to Windows 7. Obviously, something with the boot process is different than it was before. How do I fix this in Windows 7?

Comment: That random partition is called "swap". Read more about it [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq). You probably want to [fix your boot loader](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33433/restore-the-windows-boot-loader-after-an-ubuntu-update/), as you still have GRUB on there (the one used for Linux). Do you have a Windows DVD?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to keep your Linux partitions, the easiest method would be to reinstall Windows into a new partition. This should remove the Linux boot loader and replace with windows. Ideally you should be able to choose which windows partition you want to enter during the boot process. Enter your old partition and simply format the other (new) windows partition..